# Firebase Phone Authen how to send otp code and access to another activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two activity first activity for typing number to check auth for send otp code from firebase, but I need to put code in second activity with Textwatcher

Here my first activity code now can put number and go to second activity and receive Otp code and pass to second activity

```
@Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            Toast.makeText(OTP1.this,"verifucation done"+ phoneAuthCredential,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(OTP1.this,"verifucation fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(OTP1.this,"invalid mob no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(OTP1.this,"quta over" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            //Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
            Toast.makeText(OTP1.this,"Verification code sent to mobile",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;

            mResendToken = token;
            startActivity(new Intent(OTP1.this,OTP2.class));
            finish();
        }
    };

    btn_next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.nextButoon);

    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    "+66"+ put_num.getText().toString(),        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    OTP1.this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

        }
    });

}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        Toast.makeText(OTP1.this,"Verification done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        //Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            Toast.makeText(OTP1.this,"Verification failed code invalid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

And this my second activity I'm trying to use a simple code for Textwatcher and get this error

```
08-03 14:50:34.383 7790-7790/com.example.androiddev.army31 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.androiddev.army31, PID: 7790
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo.zzcF(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.example.androiddev.army31.LoginScreen.OTP2$1.onTextChanged(OTP2.java:57)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8504)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8566)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10770)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1212)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:582)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:509)
                                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:508)
                                                                                 at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6528)
                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:6318)
                                                                                 at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2740)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9948)
```

And here my second activity

```
pinView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (pinView.getText().toString().trim().length() == 6){
                PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, pinView.getText().toString());
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });





}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        Toast.makeText(OTP2.this,"Verification done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        // ...
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        //Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            Toast.makeText(OTP2.this,"Verification failed code invalid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for me was that the api_key value in my google_services.json was empty. This was because the default json file generated for me by firebase had no api_key value at all, so I just added one manually to make it work. Adding a random string value here will make the codelab work, but make sure to stop the current run and rebuild the project, otherwise the Android Studio autorun feature will run without updating the json file being used.

You can get your api key from . /console.firebase.google.com/project --> your project --> settings -->general.

and add it to your google_services.json current_key